# configure multiple networks with static and dhcp ip addresses

Tags: macos, network

At work I'd like to be able to use a `static ip` over wifi for development purposes. At home however, since I'm on a different network I don't want to use a static ip, but `dhcp`. On `OSX 10.8`, how can I configure this in a way that I don't have to manually change over each time I switch networks?

Answer (score 10):

Configure separate network Locations.

1. On the Network pane in System Preferences, use the Location pop-up
   menu to create a new location name.
2. Press the + (plus) button to create a new location.
3. Click the Done button.
4. Click the Apply button in the Network pane.

You can now configure and select separate network locations via the drop down in the Network pane.

Comment: Awesome, never even noticed that feature before. Thanks

Comment: I found this which seems to do what I'm looking for: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locations-3/id437317622?mt=12

Comment: This is an elegant solution with Mac but I still love iOS's network configuration per network. That's something we really want!